# Empty result of fetchone when querying a FTS5 table in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search

I'm trying the `Full-text Search` in `SQLite` and I'm having an issue with the `FTS5` tables.

Following [this guide](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/) I've created some virtual tables, for example:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS search_text_table USING fts5 (field_a unindexed, field_b unindexed, name, description, summary);
```

Then I can insert some data to perform text searches.

But when I want to update or delete a row on the table, I do this:

```
connection.execute("DELETE FROM search_text_table WHERE field_b = ?", [id])
connection.commit()
```

or

```
connection.execute("UPDATE search_text_table SET field_a = ?, name= ?, description = ?, summary = ? WHERE field_b = ?", [value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5])
connection.commit()
```

They are executed but the rows are no affected. But if I go to SQLite Studio and on the SQL Editor I type the same sentencee with the same values I get a result and the rows are updated or deleted.

What's happening?

Regards.

--- EDIT ---

The solution it's to use a normal DELETE or UPDATE as it's indicated on the 6th line of the documentation. On my first attempt I tried with them but I got some errors but after trying again as Shawn suggested... now works.

--- EDIT 2 ---

Changed the problem description.

Comment: That documentation is for external content tables, which you're not using, btw.

Comment: So how can I update or delete an FTS5 table?

Comment: With `delete from` like usual.

Comment: I swear you that I've tried first with a normal delete and update as it specifies on the six line of the doc and it gave me errors... Now it works, I don't understand :/ Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Hi @Shawn, I've edited the description as I'm still having the problem even with the normal delete and update sentences.